# list fo random numbers separated by commas

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Okay so I am making a mario inspired game with randomly generating terrain, It is all working fine however the array of random numbers that randomises the terrain must be the same each time so that the user can enter a seed which is then merged with the larger list to provide a set of random numbers based off of the seed however I cannot think of any way to make this array the same each time without writing it out, and even then making an array of 1000 numbers will be timely. Can anyone suggest a fast way (number generators online dont format it in one single line of numbers separated by numbers so cannot use them)
or could someone provide me with a list that is on a single line separated by numbers that i can easily copy and paste into an array thanks! :)

Comment: Dude, don't be lazy. As far as I know, using the SAME SEED WILL generate the SAME RANDOM SEQUENCE in regular random generators.

And to genereate 1000 values is not timely at all. It's piece of cake for your CPU. It does a lot more than this on other tasks.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima AFAIK JavaScript doesn't have a built-in RNG that supports custom seeds.

Comment: check out [compute-lcg](https://github.com/compute-io/lcg)

Comment: You might use a custom random() such as Mersenne Twister that supports a seed... https://gist.github.com/banksean/300494

Comment: different implementation of MT + Code example: https://plnkr.co/edit/67uJDYMFtXY3ylk3gh70?p=preview

Comment: @gcampbell I see. That will be a problem then. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code in Javascript will generate 1000 random numbers separated by commas.

```
var string = "";
var numberOfRandomNumbers = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRandomNumbers; i++) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1); //Will generate random number between 1 and 1000
    string += randomNumber+",";
}
console.log(string.substring(0, string.length - 1)); //Print string to console and remove last comma
```

Comment: @Oriol The title clearly states "list fo random numbers separated by commas". "could someone provide me with a list that is on a single line separated by numbers that i can easily copy and paste into an array thanks!". I provided the code to generate that list.

Comment: Using the code above and reading this link should get you a solution: http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/

Comment: thanks @CharlieFish that is what i wanted however What Jason Fetterly is saying sounds interesting as i didnt know you could generate random numbers based off of a seed will have to check that out

Comment: Thank you @JasonFetterly That is precisely what i wanted i just didnt realise you could do it like that